# Specialization of class template parameter compiles in GCC, Clang and MSVC but GCC selects another specialization

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-specialization

I successfully compile the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) code snippet below in Clang 8.0.0, MSVC v19.20 and GCC 8.3. Both MSVC and Clang will make the program return 0 and GCC causes the program to return 1 ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/_cpFkD)), so there is a difference and I don't know which compiler produces the correct output.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    template <typename U>
    using inner = Foo<U>;
};

template<template<typename ...Ts> typename>
struct is_foo_template : std::false_type {};
template<>
struct is_foo_template<Foo> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_foo : is_foo_template<T::template inner> {};

int main() {
    return is_foo<Foo<int>>::value;
}
```

I think that this snippet returns `is_foo<Foo<Int>>::value`, but the value is either `std::true_type::value` or `std::false_type::value` depending on if the Foo-specialization of `is_foo_template` is selected or not. But the value returned from `main` is not the same for all three compilers mentioned above, so it seems to me that not all compilers selects the same specialization.

**Question(s):** According to the standard, should the Foo-specialization be selected or should non-specialized template declaration be selected?

Comment: An interesting question. Just curious what would be the type `inner` for `Foo<int>`?

Comment: I think it's a GCC bug. In some cases it's obvious that `template <...> using` creates a new type template (e.g. `template <typename> using X = int;` can be passed to `template <typename> typename` template parameter), so I assume it creates a new type template in *all* cases.

Comment: @vahancho It would be an [alias template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), so its a family of types (not a single type). You can use the alias template to create a type, like so: `Foo<int>::inner<float>`, which is just `Foo<float>` and has nothing to do with the `typename T=int` template parameter afaik.

Comment: [CWG1286](https://wg21.link/cwg1286)